# AR.js, the object entity doesn't appear on top of the NFT marker and the size is very small

Tags: aframe, ar.js

I am trying to put an AR object using AR marker and NFT marker, and it works properly on the AR marker.
pict:
[using AR marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZQOi.jpg)

but, when I am using the NFT marker, the object entity appear quite far below the NFT marker, and the size is very small. pict:
[using NFT marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDDeU.jpg)

Why did it happen like that and how can I fix it?

Here is my source code:
[source code NFT marker](https://github.com/fitriani1021/book/blob/master/test.html) |
[source code AR marker](https://github.com/fitriani1021/book/blob/master/testhirokanji.html)

Answer (score 0):

NFT and marker-based work very differently. Try to scale your object up. From the image you attached, it seems like you can easily scale up by 50 or more. You can also position your object on the target with a bit of trial and error. I'd start with an x position value of 100 and y of 150.
To do so, add the following to your a-entity: `scale="50 50 50" position="100 150 0"`